# SQL Server Versions - Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

What is minimum version of MS SQL Server required to be able to create Linked Servers on SQL Server 2014? By version I mean Standard, Developer, Enterprise and so on. Thanks.

Comment: I would say that you could create LS starting from `Express` up to `Enterprise`. Do you need official docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Linked server from Express edition to Enterprise edition.

```
I mean you can create linked servers in all the editions.
```

Note: linked server is not supported by SQL Server Compact Edition

Comment: linked server is not supported by SQL CE

Comment: Could do provide some link to a credible source? I can't find any.